# Is it possible to use GPIO's simultaneously?

Tags: i2c, pwm, real-time

I'm interested in using raspberry to control a number of brushless motors.
PWM should be executed parallely to work in needed rate. As far as I've heard, RPi provides only consequent requests to GPIO's. 
The obvious solution here is to use I2C or SPI as a working protocol between RPi and PIC. PIC itself would translate PWM to motors simultaneously.
The question is if it's any common way of doing it? Like an add-on chip that I can put on RPi to make outputs parallel?

Comment: Isn't the problem with brushless motors the special sequencing they need to be driven?  Could you post a link to your motors?  The Pi can supply PWM independently to the gpios.

Comment: http://rctimer.com/product-1080.html - motor
http://rctimer.com/product-1059.html - ESC
The thing is I want to control 4 different ESCs with PWM in parallel, not in consequence.

Comment: That's not a problem.  The ESC does the difficult work of controlling the brushless motor.  The Pi can control the ESCs.  There are quite a few ways.  My [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library, servoblaster, pi-blaster, RPIO.GPIO, etc.